# How to get count in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

My print_r value is

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count(*)] => 1 ) )
```

Using foreach how to get row of count value
i used like this,

```
foreach($availability as $row)
echo $row->count(*);
```

But i can't get the answer.I got parse error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')'

Comment: Using an SQL alias would be easier. E.g. `count(*) as mycount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly brackets.

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->{'count(*)'} = 1;
echo '<pre>';print_r($obj->{'count(*)'});echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Or, use variable variable like this:

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->{'count(*)'} = 1;
$var="count(*)";
echo '<pre>';print_r($obj->$var);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Another solution could be use alias for `count(*)` as per @Jon Stirling's comment.

Modify your SQL query like:

```
$yourQuery = "SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM yourTable";
```

And, in your PHP code, use

```
echo $row->cnt;
```

[Working Demo 1](https://eval.in/507471)

[Working Demo 2](https://eval.in/507468)

Comment: Thank you so much i got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Besides using an alias for the count statement, use [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) rather than [mysqli_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch as array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    printf ("Num rows: %d", $row["count(*)"]);

    $result->free();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to

```
$yourQuery = "SELECT count(*) as total_row FROM yourTable";
$getResult = mysqli_query($connection, $yourQuery);      

     1. $getTotal_row= mysqli_fetch_object($connection, $getResult);   
    echo "No.of row==" . $getTotal_row->total_row;    

     2. echo "No.of row==" . $getTotal_row=mysqli_num_rows($getResult);

     3. echo "No.of row==" . $getResult->num_rows;
```